# My link attribute is not functioning between html & css sheets

Tags: html, css

I am struggling linking the below html content with css style sheet but could not solve it.

I am using the Atom text editor.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Globe Design Co</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>
```

Comment: Hi Afzal, how does your folder structure look like?

Answer (score -1):

Please follow the steps below:

- Add `<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/file.css"/>` (replace `path/to/file.css` with path to css)
- Check if the css is in the proper class
- Check the path of css file in relation with html.

If you can, please provide the github repo.

Comment: Provide file structure.